# Opening a file from command line arguments without knowing the index?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to open textfiles based on command line arguments, but I don't know the index of the argument as it could come at any point of it. 
The textfiles are titled "x_y_z". Currently I have the following code but I know that it's wrong, and I'm unsure how to approach this only using os and sys (should I be using a for or while loop or searching the range of command line arguments inputted?)

```
command_line_input = 0
while len(sys.argv) > 1:
    if command_line_input.startswith("x"):
       if os.path.isfile(command_line_input) == True:
          file = os.path.isfile(command_line_input)
           [code continues]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the arguments and check if a file with the same name is present:

```
for argument in sys.argv[1:]:  # skip the first argument as that's your script
    if argument[0] == "x" and os.path.isfile(argument):
        pass  # your code here, e.g. print("File found: " + argument)
```